# Entire SSL Certificate Chain on Traefik

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

We have a Docker Swarm Cluster with Consul + Traefik as a proxy for our microservices. Traefik v1.6.1 was installed and now we have to configure de SSL certificate.
This certificate is a wildcard certificate (*.mydomain.com) to support our micro services availables in subdomains as "microservice2.mydomain.com".

For this purpose, we would like to know if it is possible to set the entire certificate chain on Traefik, and how could it be done.

Regards,

Comment: You could have Traefik terminate the SSL connection; also, the certificates could be *injected* using Docker Secrets.

Comment: Hi Galbenu, we have the certificate as a consul key/value and in this way we are able to call a micro service using the browser and the certificate is loaded, but without the CA certificate.

We suppose it is occurring because the missing of the entire certificate chain on Traefik. Does Traefiik support the entire SSL certificate Chain? How?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/984

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot. We concatenated the certificate and now the CA is ok at the clients (browser).

Thank you.